# Laravel Validation 3 fields but only one is required

Tags: laravel, validation

I like to ask if anyone knows how to validate 3 fields but you must fill only one, not the other 2.

Example :

```
<input name="field1" type="numeric">
<input name="field2" type="numeric">
<input name="field3" type="numeric">
```

field1,field2,field2 can be filled but if i fill field1, field2 and field3 passes, but if i fill field1 and field2, validation triggered and only one of them can be filled.

Thanks

Comment: is this in the view.blade.php or in the controller?

Comment: Please make rules and use this code "Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules)". Please follow this link for more help https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-required-without-all

Comment: I tested that , but let me fill all the fields ..

Answer (score 1):

try this:

**Controller**

```
public function store() {
  User::create(request()->validate([
    'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
    'middle_name' => 'nullable',
    'last_name' => 'nullable',
  ]))
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  Validator::make($request()->all, [
    'number_1' => Rule::requiredIf(!$request->number_2 && !$request->number_3);
    'number_2' => Rule::requiredIf(!$request->number_1 && !$request->number_3);
    'number_3' => Rule::requiredIf(!$request->number_1 && !$request->number_2);
  ])
}
```

Comment: All three fields are numeric , and only one  must be filled not the first , can be  the first , can be  the lastone or the middleone  ,but not all  of them.

Comment: I just Tried but kept  passing if i fill two of the tree fields ... i mean , i need one  of those fields fill but not two or tree ... 
I just edited what you wrote above like this  :
` 'number1' => Rule::requiredIf(!$this->number2 && !$this->number3),
            'number2' => Rule::requiredIf(!$this->number1 && !$this->number2),
            'number3' => Rule::requiredIf(!$this->number1 && !$this->number3),`
Im using a request class.

Comment: I think you need to deal with `front end`, so you need javascript. You can use `jquery` and it should be like this `$('.inputs').change(function() { if(! $('.inputs').val()) { $('.inputs').removeAttr('disabled') } $('.inputs').attr('disabled') $(this).removeAttr('disabled') })`

Answer (score 0):

Put the must filled field as `required`.For others just put the validation rule,don't put `required` rule..

```
 $this->validate($request, [
    'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'second_name' => 'string|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
    ]);
```

Comment: All three fields are numeric , and only one must be filled not the first , can be the first , can be the lastone or the middleone ,but not all of them

Answer (score -1):

`sometimes` will validate if it passed

```
'field1' => 'sometimes|required|max:255',
'field2' => 'sometimes|required|max:255',
'field3' => 'sometimes|required|max:255',
```